# Qualitative graph for a Cauchy problem's solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I guys.
I have to draw the qualitative graph of this Cauchy problem:

$$\begin{cases}
y'(x)=-\frac{y(x)}{1+e^{y(x)}} \\ 
y(0)=1\\
\end{cases}$$
What road should I have to follow to don't go in troubles? Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods